# Is there a shell command that opens multiple images in one instance of the microsoft photos app?

Tags: command-line, shell, images, photos

I'm on Windows 11 and let's say I have a folder that contains a few JPEG images. If I navigate to that folder, highlight the images and hit 'enter' it opens all the images in one window of the Microsoft photos app that enables me to scroll nicely among all of them.

Is there a shell command that does the same thing?

Note that if I run `start filename1.jpg filename2.jpg` it only opens the first file, and if I separate the commands into two separate commands, it opens them both but in separate windows, which I do not want.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "a shell command" ?

Comment: Something you can write in the terminal or in bash. (I thought the term for that was "shell" command; apologies if that's wrong!)

Comment: To do what ? Select files and open them ? This is very unclear.

Comment: Does this work? `Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Path\To\Your\Folder" -Filter *.jpg | ForEach-Object { Invoke-Item $_.FullName }`

Comment: If it does i'll add it as an answer

Comment: Nevermind, it works for me when testing. Will add it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

In powershell:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Path\To\Your\Folder" -Filter *.jpg | ForEach-Object { Invoke-Item $_.FullName }
```

Just change the path to the one that contains your images and test. You should find all the photo's open, but only one instance of Microsoft Photos is running inside task manager.